# toPromise is not a function of yeoman RunContext

Tags: node.js, promise, mocha.js, yeoman

I'm trying to write unit tests for a yeoman generator using `yeoman-test`. The generator runs properly when I use the configuration which is used in the following code on the command line.

```
var path = require('path');
var helpers = require('yeoman-test');

describe('full test', function() {
    before(function() {
        return helpers.run(path.join(__dirname, '../../app'))
        .withOptions({})
        .withArguments(path.join(__dirname, '../resources/extSolMarked'))
        .withPrompts({
            name: "newExtSol",
            namespace: "newNamespace",
            angular: "1.5",
            kendo: true,
            webapi: true
        })
        .toPromise();
    });

    it("check", function() {
        //check results and stuff
    });
});
```

Executing this entering `mocha generatorTest.js` on the command line leads to

```
TypeError: helpers.run(...).withOptions(...).withArguments(...).withPrompts(...).toPromise is not a function
```

A very similar example can be found on the yeoman websites [here](http://yeoman.io/authoring/testing.html) and I can't figure out the difference between this two snippets.

UPDATE: I'm using yeoman-test@1.1.0

2nd Update: Finally found a workaround by myself using `.on('end', done)`

Comment: Can you update the post with your version of `yeoman-test`?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include that